# Why can't I find the source code of the JDialog Box in the Pentaho Report

Tags: java, swing, pentaho, executable-jar

We have a Java Swing application that uses Pentaho and Jasper Reports for reporting documents. When we open a report which uses Pentaho, it displays a Jdialog box that has both a jLabel and a jTextfield along with the report. The report file is in .prpt format, which we are able to open using Pentaho designing tools, but we cannot find the source code for that jDialog box anywhere in the codebase.

This report, along with the dialog box, opens when we click a jButton. While debugging, we found there is a class being called named "Launcher.java" which in turn loads a jar file named "Launcher.java". Then the debugger breaks out of the action performed from that button, and the report is displayed.

Lastly, there is also an exe file named Launcher.exe. So, where does the source code of the jDialog live?.

I suspect the jar.

Comment: Consider adding relevant code.

Comment: Mostly grammar and clarity.

Comment: you have to take source-code and open in java editor, that package will be different i believe.